# Eclipse Makefile project and Visual C++ compiler

Tags: visual-c++, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I'm attempting to use Eclipse (CDT) in order to make a portable C++ makefile project that I can take and compile on different platforms. I'm settings up build configurations to use each platforms native compiler. For Windows, this means Visual C++.

I'm running into two separate issues, at the moment. The first one is that I can't get Eclipse to recognize the include path I'm trying to work with. On my computer, I have the compiler located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include`. I went into my project settings under my Windows-specific build configuration and I added that to C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes -> C++ Source File. Eclipse still complains that it cannot find the files I'm trying to include.

The second problem I'm having is that make cannot find the compiler executable. I'm using a copy of make installed through Cygwin, which may or may not be the problem. I was wondering if there was a make-like program for Windows that I could use to build my project for Windows.

Sorry for the two questions in one, I just thought it'd be easier to kill two birds with one stone.

Comment: Program Files (x86) appears as Program Files to 32bit programs.